# OrderBy - how exactly is implemented?

Tags: c#

How .NET knows what fields has to order? According to definition:
Enumerable.OrderBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)
the fields are selected by a Tkey, but that only provides the value of the field not the field itself.
Here is an example:

```
class Cls1
{
  public string a;
  public string b;
}

string keysel2(Cls1 c)
{
  return c.a;
}

string keysel3(Cls1 c)
{
  return c.b;
}
```

and later we have:

```
List<Cls1> cls1list = new List<Cls1>();

void f()
{
 cls1list.Add(new Cls1 { a = "3", b = "a" });
 cls1list.Add(new Cls1 { a = "2", b = "b" });
 cls1list.Add(new Cls1 { a = "1", b = "c" });

 IEnumerable<Cls1> cls2list = cls1list.OrderBy(keysel2);

 foreach (Cls1 item in cls2list)
 {
    string s = item.a;
    string s1 = item.b;
 }
}
```

So OrderBy has nothing in it directly linked to a member field of Cls1. How does the compiler get the info about the actual field?

Comment: there is some implicit delegate wrapping your passed in method `keysel2`, that delegate stores the info of your method, execute that method each time it need to get something to order...

Comment: I really don't understand what your question is. The `OrderBy` method obtains a set of values, knows what their type is (since this information is encoded into the type of the delegate being passed into it) and organises the objects in the list it is invoked on based on a default comparer for the type returned by the delegate. Why would the compiler need info "about the actual field"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to OrderBy is like this:   `cls1list.OrderBy(keysel2);`

For every item in our cls1list collection, OrderBy will call keysel2, which returns the 'a' string.  OrderBy then calls Compare on pairs of strings, which allows it to sort the items.

You might not have recognised that the `keysel2` part of the OrderBy expression is referring to a method, which is called on each object in the collection - an alternative way of writing this, which is functionally equivalent would be:

`cls1list.OrderBy(item => keysel2(item));`

OrderBy is doing something like this:

```
foreach(Cls1 currentItem in items)
{
    Cls1 nextItem = ... (get the next item from items by magic)
    object currentKey = keysel2(currentItem); // This returns a string into currentKey
    object nextKey = keysel2(nextItem); // This returns a string into currentKey

    if(currentKey.Compare(nextKey))
    {
       ... // Swap the items (or not, depending on the ordering you want)
       // Note that OrderBy hasn't looked into the Cls1 items itself at all, it's just looked at the objects it got back from calling keysel2.

    }
}
```

The point about passing the key-select delegate into OrderBy is that it means that OrderBy doesn't need to know anything at all about the type of objects it's sorting - all it needs to know is that if it calls the key-select method, that method will return something it can use to decide what order the objects come in.   You can view the key-select delegate as a kind of 'interpreter' - it's something which understands your Cls1 objects and can translate them into something general-purpose which OrderBy can understand.

Comment: Actually keysel2 returns a string (the value of 'a' member) not the member itself. What do I miss here?

Comment: @user628661 That is exactly what Will says in his answer.

Comment: It returns a string, which is the value of the member - OrderBy then compares the strings.  It would still work if you made your keysel method return 'object'.

Comment: I don't get it. OrderBy compares what strings? How does it know to compare with a and not with b?

Comment: @user628661 OrderBy compares the strings returned by the delegate passed into it. This would be the `a` string, since you passed in `keysel2` and not `keysel3`.

Comment: @user628661 - OrderBy calls keysel2 for each item - keysel2 returns the 'a' string, and not the 'b' string.

Comment: Yes, but how does OrderBy know that the string is from a and not b? From what it knows, it's just a string?

Comment: @user628661 - I think I see where you're coming from - OrderBy doesn't know where the string came from - it doesn't know anything about the Cls1 objects at all.  All it knows is that if it calls the method you provide (keysel2 in this case), you'll give it a key it can compare.  OrderBy doesn't need to know where that key came from, because it doesn't know anything about the kind of object it's sorting.

Comment: @user628661 It doesn't know.  It doesn't *care*.  It is the responsibility of the delegate to turn each item into a string.  From the point of view of `OrderBy`, the delegate takes care of translating the object to the key all on its own.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<Cls1,string>` takes a parameter of type Cls1 and returns a string.  `cls1list.OrderBy(keysel2);` is legal because the Method group `keysel2` is implicitly convertible to the `Func<Cls1,string>`.  Here I define a similar method and pull the same trick.  In the end all we get is a string:

```
    F(keysel2);//Invoke

    string F(Func<Cls1, string> func)
    {
        string orderByResult = func(new Cls1 { a = "4", b = "d" });
        return orderByResult;
    }
```

The implementation of `Func<TSource, TKey>` does not matter to `OrderBy`.  The Delegate need only be compatible with the `Func<,>`.  `OrderBy` will invoke the delegate for each item in the collection.  It will use the value returned by the delegate to perform it's operations, in this case ordering.